# PayPal sandbox differs from Live mode

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

So I've been struggling with PayPal's IPNs for a while now. I finally got everything working in sandbox mode, but when I went live, it didn't work.

Take a look at this:

**Sandbox (Works and sends IPN)**

`<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">`

[image]

**Live (Doesn't send IPN)**

`<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">`

[image]

See how the two payment screens are different? The sandbox one sends the IPN just fine, but the live one doesn't. Why could this be happening? Why is there a difference?

Comment: Are you passing the `notify_url` field in your form post?

Comment: Yes, `<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://blah.ngrok.io/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=eab_paypal_ipn&amp;blog_id=1&amp;booking_id=12402">` It's one of the button's hidden fields

Comment: Can you post the transaction ID from one of your live transactions?

Comment: Transaction ID: 8JM56114FN385860L

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have two issues going on here:

1. IPN was disabled on the merchant's account.  This happens if PayPal receives continual failures when trying to send IPNs to you — PayPal will warn you by email first; if we're still unable to send IPNs to you after that, we'll disable IPN on the account entirely.  I've re-enabled IPN on the account for you, but if this happens again in the future, you'll need to [file a ticket with our Merchant Technical Support team](https://www.paypal-techsupport.com) to get it re-enabled.
2. I asked the system to re-send the IPN to you for the transaction you provided, but we're getting "404 Not Found" errors back from your website when we do.  You might need to double-check that your `notify_url` is correct.  In the future, you can ask PayPal to re-send IPNs from [this page](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history) in your PayPal account.

Comment: Thanks, Matt, how can I check if IPN is disabled in an account?

Comment: You should get an email notification when it's been disabled.  Past that -- if you go to the IPN history page (link in #2 above) and you see the status for all of your IPNs as "Disabled", then you know that IPN is disabled for your account.

Comment: Now I get this error in my logs: 

`<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>
 
You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;paypal&#46;com&#47;cgi&#45;bin&#47;webscr" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;e0e33f17&#46;1482335172&#46;7168a5
</BODY>
</HTML>`

When my listener tries to verify the IPN calling: `https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr`

Comment: Not sure what's going on here.  Are you sure you're posting this to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr and not http://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr ?  (I believe PayPal has blocked IPN validation requests that are taking place over HTTP and not HTTPS.)